# HtmlUnit Javascript error when getting Page

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit

I'm new to interacting with websites in Java, and I am having trouble getting a webpage with htmlUnit 2.18.  I've tried to change the URL to other websites(like google), and those pages have loaded.  But when I try to load the page my program needs I get the attached errors.  I've steped through my program and it is breaking on the line `final HtmlPage loginPage = browser.getPage(LOGIN_PAGE);`

Java File:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlSubmitInput;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTextInput;

public class WebCrawler {
    public static final String USERNAME = "Foo";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "Foo2";
    public static final String LOGIN_PAGE = "https://idp.mlslistings.com/idp/Authn/UserPassword";

    private WebClient browser;

    public void login(){
        try {
            final HtmlPage loginPage = browser.getPage(LOGIN_PAGE);
            final HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getFormByName("loginform");
            final HtmlTextInput userID = loginForm.getInputByName("j_username");
            final HtmlTextInput userPassword = loginForm.getInputByName("password");
            final HtmlSubmitInput loginButton = loginForm.getInputByName("login");

            userID.setValueAttribute(USERNAME);
            userPassword.setValueAttribute(USERNAME);

            final HtmlPage homePage = loginButton.click();

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public WebCrawler(){
        browser = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Sep 20, 2015 9:07:38 AM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking setHref
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:865)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:747)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:722)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:945)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:351)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:276)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1040)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:253)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:199)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:476)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:350)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
at WebCrawler.login(WebCrawler.java:21)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking setHref
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:181)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:311)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2887)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:547)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2570)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1674)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1669)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1255)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:310)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:738)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
... 33 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2067)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Location.setHref(Location.java:241)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
... 48 more

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:189)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:179)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1321)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1238)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2063)
... 54 more

Enclosed exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking setHref
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:181)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject$GetterSlot.setValue(ScriptableObject.java:311)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putImpl(ScriptableObject.java:2887)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.put(ScriptableObject.java:547)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptableObject.putProperty(ScriptableObject.java:2570)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1674)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.setObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1669)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1255)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:310)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3286)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:738)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:850)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:747)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:722)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:945)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeInlineScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:351)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:411)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:276)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3126)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2093)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:920)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:1040)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:253)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:199)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:476)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:350)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:415)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:400)
at WebCrawler.login(WebCrawler.java:21)
at Main.main(Main.java:7)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2067)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Location.setHref(Location.java:241)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
... 48 more

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.httpclient.HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(HtmlUnitSSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:189)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:179)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1321)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1238)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.download(WebClient.java:2063)
... 54 more
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
browser.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

after

```
browser = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
```

To Ahmed Ashour: maybe it is a bad default value?