# Cannot get web page with HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, html, htmlunit

I have a webpage I am trying to scrape from, and I'm using HtmlUnit because some of the elements of the page are rendered client-side in javascript. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String symbol = "MSFT";
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
    HtmlPage page = null;
    try {
        page = webClient.getPage("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + symbol + "/?p=" + symbol);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
    List<String> elements = page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"quoteNewsStream-0-Stream\"]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/h3/a/text()");
    for (String e : elements){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run this code, I get this exception:

```
run:
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:34 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[49] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function getOwnPropertySymbols in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23#49)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function getOwnPropertySymbols in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23#49)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:898)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
    at htmlunittest.HtmlUnitTest.main(HtmlUnitTest.java:40)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getOwnPropertySymbols in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23#49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4007)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2402)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1342)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    ... 32 more
Enclosed exception: 
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function getOwnPropertySymbols in object function Object() { [native code] }. (https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23#49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4007)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2402)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1342)
    at script(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script.e(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script.e(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script.a(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at script(https://www.yahoo.com/polyfill.min.js?features=locale-data-en-us%2Cpromise%2Carray.isarray%2Carray.prototype.every%2Carray.prototype.foreach%2Carray.prototype.indexof%2Carray.prototype.map%2Cdate.now%2Cfunction.prototype.bind%2Cobject.keys%2Cstring.prototype.trim%2Cobject.defineproperty%2Cobject.defineproperties%2Cobject.create%2Cobject.freeze%2Carray.prototype.filter%2Carray.prototype.reduce%2Cobject.assign%2Crequestanimationframe%2Cintl&version=2.1.23:49)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:769)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:883)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
    at htmlunittest.HtmlUnitTest.main(HtmlUnitTest.java:40)
======= EXCEPTION END ========

Apr 06, 2017 2:29:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:36 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:37 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: set-cookie http-equiv meta tag: invalid cookie 'rx= ; path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; Domain=;'; reason: 'Blank or null value for domain attribute'.
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:37 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript isExecutionNeeded
WARNING: Script is not JavaScript (type: text/x-safeframe, language: ). Skipping execution.
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:39 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'application/x-javascript'.
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebConsole error
SEVERE: Rehydrate returned error null
Apr 06, 2017 2:29:40 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine handleJavaScriptException
INFO: Caught script exception
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://s.yimg.com/os/finance/dd-site/js/main.bc645a6f594da6a2c95e.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "getComponentContext" of undefined (https://s.yimg.com/os/finance/dd-site/js/main.bc645a6f594da6a2c95e.js#1)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "getComponentContext" of undefined (https://s.yimg.com/os/finance/dd-site/js/main.bc645a6f594da6a2c95e.js#1)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:898)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:637)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:518)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:778)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:754)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:980)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:352)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$2.execute(HtmlScript.java:239)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:258)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:781)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:738)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1243)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1143)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:226)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:345)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3154)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2117)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:945)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:521)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.cyberneko.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:472)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:988)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:246)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:160)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:520)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:311)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:459)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:444)
    at htmlunittest.HtmlUnitTest.main(HtmlUnitTest.java:40)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot call method "getComponentContext" of undefined (https://s.yimg.com/os/finance/dd-site/js/main.bc645a6f594da6a2c95e.js#1)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefCallError(ScriptRuntime.java:3956)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2390)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2384)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1342)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:416)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Promise$2.execute(Promise.java:272)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.doProcessPostponedActions(JavaScriptEngine.java:949)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.access$2(JavaScriptEngine.java:919)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:893)
    ... 32 more
```

There were two other similarly-long exceptions, but there is not enough space in the character limit to accommodate them.

From what I can tell, the program is running into problems when it tried to create the HtmlPage object in the first try-catch block. Is there anything that I'm obviously doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681768/htmlunit-javascript-error-when-getting-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the latest available version. If the problem persists open an issue in the HtmlUnit bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This was just [fixed](https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/14002) by basic implementation of `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`.

You can get latest build from [here](https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts) (once green).

Your case now works with changing:

```
List<String> elements = page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"quoteNewsStream-0-Stream\"]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/h3/a/text()");
for (String e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

to

```
List<DomText> elements = page.getByXPath("//*[@id=\"quoteNewsStream-0-Stream\"]/ul/li[1]/div/div/div[1]/h3/a/text()");
for (DomText e : elements) {
    System.out.println(e.asText());
}
```

Comment: Is build #2652 the build you're referring to? It's the latest successful build. I tried again with the changes you suggested in this answer, but I am getting the same exception as before.

Comment: Actually, the commit was after `#2652`. Now the last successful build is `#2676`, which you should use.